# Minecraft Spigot Plugin YML File is overwriting custom input in file

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft

I make a plugin for my Minecraft Server and everything works well.
I use a users.yml file to store some data for every user like the groups and uuid.

Something weird is happening now, and I don't know how to solve it:
My users.yml is generating fine, no problems. All data is saved in there and I can access it.
BUT when I try to edit for example the group of the user from the default (this is the group that's assigned to every new user) to admin in the file itself and the user is joining again, the file overwrites the group to default.

What do I not see in the codes below to prevent the overwrite or did I do something wrong?

This is the function that creates the users.yml file:

```java
    public class UserList {

    private static File usersFile;
    private static FileConfiguration usersConf;

    public static void Setup(){
        usersFile = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder(), "users.yml");

        if(!usersFile.exists()){
            try {
                usersFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error creating Usersfile: " + e);
            }
        }
        usersConf = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(usersFile);
    }

    public static FileConfiguration get(){
        return usersConf;
    }

    public static void Save(){
        try {
            usersConf.save(usersFile);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error saving Usersfile: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void reload(){
        usersConf = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(usersFile);
    }
}
```

This is the code in the onEnabled() function:

```java
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        instance = this;
        if (!getDataFolder().exists()) getDataFolder().mkdir();

        //Erstelle users.yml mit Standardwerten
        UserList.Setup();
        UserList.get().addDefault("groups.admin.prefix", "§c");
        UserList.get().addDefault("groups.vip.prefix", "§6");
        UserList.get().addDefault("groups.default.prefix", "§7");
        UserList.get().options().copyDefaults(false);
        UserList.Save();

        //Hole alle Usergruppen
        Set<String> groups = UserList.get().getConfigurationSection("groups").getKeys(false);

        //Events Registrieren
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }
```

And here is the code that executes when a player is joining on the server:

```java
    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        if (UserList.get().get("users." + p.getName() + ".group") == null){  //<- I tried to prevent it with this if-statement but the problem must be elsewhere
            UserList.get().set("users." + p.getName() + ".group", "default");
        }
        UserList.get().set("users." + p.getName() + ".uuid", p.getUniqueId().toString());
        UserList.Save();

        if (!p.hasPlayedBefore()) e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + p.getName() + ChatColor.WHITE + " is new on this Server!");
        else e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + p.getName() + ChatColor.WHITE + " is " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Online");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's thie line that create the issue:

```
UserList.get().options().copyDefaults(false);
```

You should use `saveDefaultConfig()` which will write the config if (and only if) the config file doesn't exist.

This method should be call with your plugin instance, and will works with your `config.yml` file.

If you want to copy a file when it doesn't exist, you should do like that :

```java
File usersFile = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder(), "users.yml");
if(!usersFile.exists()){
    try (InputStream in = pl.getResource("users.yml");
               OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(usersFile)) {
        ByteStreams.copy(in, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(usersFile);
```